# Best way to update a listview based on date from a firestore collection

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document in firestore having a name field and a date field.I also have a stream setup which fetches data from firestore like below

```
    List<Object> _objectDetailsfromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
          return Object(
            date: doc.data['date'] ?? Timestamp.now(),
            name: doc.data['name'] ?? ''
          );
        }).toList();
      }
Stream<List<Object>> get objList {
    return collection.snapshots().map(_objectDetailsfromSnapshot);
  }
```

And then am using the where condition to fetch the items for today. Using this am populating a listview.
The issue is when the current date changes from yesterday to today, my list view still shows the items of yesterday.
I want the listview to automatically show today's items. What way I can adopt to achieve this.Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's a stream, it should automatically change if you update the date or post something new. Check the date format properly. For saving the date in Firestore use,

```
'date' : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

And the stream will be

```
Firestore.instance.collection('objects').orderBy('date', descending: true).snapshots(),
```

Then in your StreamBuilder

```
return Container(
ListView(
children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) => 
_objectList(doc)).toList(),
),
),
```

```
Widget _objectList(DocumentSnapshot doc){
return ListTile(
title: Text(documentSnapshot.data['name']),
subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot.data['name']),
);
}
```

Comment: It's not happening automatically because the firestore date is not changing. In my stream am fetching all the list of objects and then filtering based on date. When my current date changes from yesterday to today, I want to fetch the items corresponding to today's date.

Comment: Firestore field values doesn't change automatically. But you can use Cloud Functions to update the field values to todays date after 24hrs or something. I'm not sure how you can do that. Look into some examples.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. but I think you haven't got the question. I don't want to change the date in firestore. For example, I have a document with date field and name field. i have values for today and yesterday. If I have opened the app yesterday, my listview will have yesterday's data. but when the date changes to today, the listview is only getting updated after a app restart. I want the listview to be updated automatically when the date changes.